# How to smooth out the slope between two fragments?

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting

I have a model where the curve between the two surfaces needs to be smoothed.

The one near the left border of the red rectangle and the other on the opposite side. What I need to do, is change the angle between the two fragments.

[image: lines]

I think the 2nd image speaks for itself. The red line shows how it looks right now and the green one shows the effect that I'm looking for.

[image: screenshot explaining the problem]

Does anyone know how can I achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your mesh selected go in to [sculpt mode](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Sculpt_Mode).

Choose the *Smooth brush* by pressing <kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> and drag over the places you want smoothed.

---

If you do not want to use sculpt mode.

In edit mode, select all of the vertices, by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>. Then click on the button on the tool shelf, on the *Tools* tab under *Deform:* called **Smooth Vertex**. You can adjust the number of iterations the smoothing runs in the bottom of the tool shelf, or by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>.
[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip! It takes some time, but it works :). However, I'd like to know if there's any kind of self-generating algorithm that fills the space between two chosen "areas" of a model.

Comment: @Marcin I see what you are looking for, will edit my answer now.

Comment: Thank you! I've been playing around with your solution and I'm satisfied :)

Comment: @Marcin glad I could help.